# IDENTITY_INSERT Error in table I am not even trying to Insert?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, identity-insert

I am getting this Error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
> table 'Unterwerke' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

..when I am Trying to insert something into the table "Clients". Every Client has 1 Unterwerk but i am never inserting an Unterwerk in my code.

This is how I insert the client:

```
public void Insert(Client entity)
{
    _context.Clients.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here's the Client object:

```
public async void addClient()
        {
            Client client;
            client = new Client();
            client.Hostname = newHostname;
            client.IP = newIP;
            client.MAC = newMAC;
            client.Subnetmask = newSubnet;
            client.Gateway = newGateway;

            using (var repo = new UnterwerkRepository(contextFactory.CreateDbContext()))
            {
                client.Unterwerk = await repo.GetById(newUW);
            }


            using (var repo = new ClientRepository(contextFactory.CreateDbContext()))
            {
                repo.Insert(client);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the client argument that you are passing to the Insert method?

Comment: is there any trigger defined on "Clients"-table which references "Unterwerke"?

Comment: Check if you ID column at this table as identity(1,1) and check in entity object client Id as default value 0)

Comment: @Sergey no there is not

Comment: @C1sc0 I've added it do my question

Comment: client.Unterwerk = await repo.GetById(newUW); instead of this just use client.Unterwerk = new Unterwerk(); or leave it on the default value

Comment: @C1sc0 newUW is an int that I use to get the correct Unterwerk like this:
`public async Task<Unterwerk> GetById(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Unterwerke.FindAsync(id);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client model, you should define the `Unterwerk` like this (foreign key convention):

```
class Client 
{
    public Unterwerk Unterwerk {get;set;}
    public int UnterwerkId {get;set;}
}
```

and when you inserting a client just fill the `UnterwerkId` property that you got from the `UnterwerkRepository`.

Comment: Oh I just set `client.UnterwerkID = newUW` and it works

Comment: EF tries to insert that as a new Unterwerk (with the same Id, that is why you got the IDENTITY_INSERT error), just try to fill the UnterwerkId.